# Get the background color of a button in android

Tags: android, button, background-color

How do i get the background color of a button.
In the xml i set the background color using ---- android:background = XXXXX
now in the activity class how can i retrieve this value that it has ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know how to retrieve the actual color.

It's easy to get this as a `Drawable`

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
Drawable buttonBackground = button.getBackground();
```

If you know this is a color then you can try

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
```

And if you're on Android 3.0+ you can get out the resource id of the color.

```
int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
```

And compare this to your assigned colors, ie.

```
if (colorID == R.color.green) {
  log("color is green");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure getColor() gets the id?  I think it gets the actual int value of the color (ie. 0xAARRGGBB).  I tested this with "#00000001" and it returned 1.

Comment: In my test I did `button.setBackground(R.color.green)` and then checked the response and it definitely wasn't the actual color id. I'd prefer a proper color integer so I can `Color.red(int)`, `Color.green(int)`, `Color.blue(int)` it. But in my test on Android 3.2, this wasn't the case. I'd guess that it's inconsistent, returning a color int, or resid, depending on context.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do a task only if the background image of an image button is a certain drawable resource. How can I compare... I've tried   if(buttonBackground.equals(@drawable/mydrawable)) but it doesn't work

Comment: I used this `((ColorDrawable) row.getBackground()).getColor()` as `(row.background as ColorDrawable).color`  but i faced with this error `android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable`

Answer (score 19):

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Rect mBounds;

public void initIfNeeded() {
  if(mBitmap == null) {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mBounds = new Rect();
  }
}

public int getBackgroundColor(View view) {
  // The actual color, not the id.
  int color = Color.BLACK;

  if(view.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      initIfNeeded();

      // If the ColorDrawable makes use of its bounds in the draw method,
      // we may not be able to get the color we want. This is not the usual
      // case before Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.1 r1).
      // Yet, we change the bounds temporarily, just to be sure that we are
      // successful.
      ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable)view.getBackground();

      mBounds.set(colorDrawable.getBounds()); // Save the original bounds.
      colorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1); // Change the bounds.

      colorDrawable.draw(mCanvas);
      color = mBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);

      colorDrawable.setBounds(mBounds); // Restore the original bounds.
    }
    else {
      color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
    }
  }

  return color;
}
```

Comment: I used this `((ColorDrawable) row.getBackground()).getColor()` as `(row.background as ColorDrawable).color` but i faced with this error `android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable`

Comment: You should not cast `row.getBackground()` to `ColorDrawable` without checking first if it is indeed a `ColorDrawable`. That's why I start with `if(view.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable)`.
In the case of a `StateListDrawable` (a `DrawableContainer`) you might need to work with `drawable.getCurrent()`. However, that alone might not suffice. It really depends on the drawable's structure.
Also, be mindful that this snippet has almost 7 years and a lot has changed since then. Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

You can also try something like set the color value as the tag like

```
android:tag="#ff0000"
```

And access it from the code

```
String colorCode = (String)btn.getTag();
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, also work : @color/your_color,   or,  ?attr/colorPrimary

Comment: Everything ingenious is simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The simpliest way to get the color for me is:

```
int color = ((ColorDrawable)button.getBackground()).getColor();
```

Tested and working on Lollipop 5.1.1

Answer (score 2):

To get the background `Drawable`, you use

```
public Drawable getBackground();
```

as defined in the base `View` class.

Don't forget that the `Button` can have a background that is an image, a color, a gradient. If you use android:background="#ffffff", the class of the background will be

> android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

From there you can simply call

```
public int getColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_view.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);        
ColorDrawable corItem = (ColorDrawable) list_view.getChildAt(position).getBackground();
if(corItem.getColor() == Color.YELLOW){
   Toast.makeText(NovoProcessoActivity.this,"Right Color!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else{
   Toast.makeText(NovoProcessoActivity.this,"Wrong Color!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

or

```
int color =( (ColorDrawable)  list_view.getChildAt(position).getBackground()).getColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int colornumber=((ColorDrawable)v.getBackground()).getColor();
```

This is the best and simple way to get the color of a View (Button, TextView...)

To get set color to a View using java we use

```
v.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorname_you_used));
```