# Android View.getBackgroundColor #XXXXXXXX

Tags: android

The background color of my View is #FFFFFFFF. I want to get this through code. I do not want to just put #FFFFFFFF into the method because I will be changing the background through code, so this value will change all the time.

```
public void toggleEraser() {
    ImageView btnEraser = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgEraser);
    ImageView btnBrush = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgBrush);
    if (erase) {
        btnEraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.greyeraser);
        btnBrush.setImageResource(R.drawable.brush);
    } else {
        btnEraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.eraser);
        btnBrush.setImageResource(R.drawable.greybrush);
    }
    erase = !erase;
    if (erase){

                    //Here is the problem
        drawView.setColor(//drawView.getBackgroundColor());


    }
    else
        drawView.setColor(brushColor);
    drawView.setErase(erase);
}
```

Comment: see ColorDrawable docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the color you want `0xFFFFFFFF` in somevariable and then 
change `drawView.setColor(` to `drawView.setBackgroundColor(somevariable);`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer: [Get the background color of a button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089054/get-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-android). it is a little different but can lead you on the right path.