# set background resource from other view

Tags: android

i need to set background resource for my button from another button

I am trying it, but it doesn't work

```
button1.setBackground(button2.getBackground());
```

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089054/get-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
        final Drawable backgroundDrawable = button2.getBackground();
        if (backgroundDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            button1.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
        }else if (backgroundDrawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                          final ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable)   backgroundDrawable;
                       button1.setBackgroundColor(colorDrawable.getColor());
            }
         }
```

Hope it will help.