# Android-Get Background color of listview(item) programmatically

Tags: android, listview, background-color

First I create a background color for listview items like below,
I have two custom listview like this:

[image]

My custom list for setting color:

Code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_one, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    MainActivity.counter = Color.BLUE;
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    MainActivity.counter = Color.YELLOW;
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    MainActivity.counter = Color.GREEN;
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    MainActivity.counter = Color.MAGENTA;
                }
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

When user click on listview it changes to specifed color as above image,

i need to get the color of listview saved in the list when click teh button.

How can i do that, Need help pls

In my MainActivity I have button ,

```
check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
 check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You want the background of the individual row or the entire list?

Comment: @amalBit For entire list view

Comment: use settag and gettag

Comment: @amalBit I need For Entire listview and if possible can u tell me for single list item value too . tnq

Comment: Listview is just another view at the end of the day. Sp you can try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8089242/2219600

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain a view background colour, from a ListView

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
```

to obtain background try

```
Drawable listDrawableBackground = listView.getBackground();
```

if background is a colour, to obtain the colour, you can try

```
ColorDrawable listViewColor = (ColorDrawable) listView.getBackground();
```

to get the actual colour, use

```
int colorId = listViewColor.getColor();
```

you can compare this colorId with existing color like so:

`if (colorID == R.color.blue) {
   Log("color is blue");
}`

Another way will be to add a tag to the ListView, and the tag will be the color, say

tag = "#ccc", and you can use

```
String colorCode = (String)listView.getTag();
```

now you have the colorCode and you can reuse it anywhere in your program.

Comment: I didnt get color using this can u tell me using button for getting entire list row