# java.lang.ClassCastException when trying to get background color of a button

Tags: android, android-background

I want when a button is clicked to get it's background color.If the background color is the same with a color in resources named *"blue_color"*, make background transparent.Else make it *"blue_color"*. I have tried the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089242/7101450) but it gives me the error.

Code:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                ColorDrawable btc = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();
                int colorId = btc.getColor();
                if(colorId == R.color.blue_color){
                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               }else{
               btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
               }
             }
   });
```

error from logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

in the line where is

> ColorDrawable btc = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();

Comment: The color will never be `R.color.blue_color`, because `R.color.blue_color` is not a color. It is an identifier of a color resource. I suggest that you use a separate `boolean` or other field to track the state of your button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `btn.getBackground().getColor();`

In your code you are getting a drawable...
So the line should be:

```
ColorDrawable btc = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground().getColor();
```

**Edit:** You can get an int id of the color from resources like this:

```
int alpha = ... // 0-255
int blueColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.blue_color, null);
int blueColorWithAlpha = Color.argb( 
alpha, 
Color.red(blueColor), Color.green(blueColor), Color.blue(blueColor) );
```

The id of the color is now `blueColorWithAlpha` so you can compare it with the one of the button.. To get the color id of the button you can do so: `int color = ((ColorDrawable)button.getBackground()).getColor();`

I haven't tested this code but did some search and found these snippets on stackoverflow...

Comment: I can't use ColorDrawable btc = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground().getColor();   There is a message saying "Cannot resolve method 'getColor"

Comment: Try this: Drawable background = btn..getBackground(); if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) { Color color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor(); }

Comment: Required android.graphics.Color , found int in Color color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();