# How to get color from Button when background set as drawable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, drawable

I have a `<Button/>`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Button background is set as `android:background="@drawable/btn_color"` where `btn_color` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

I need to get the color `#FF0000` of the button in my code. What I have tried is

```
val drawable = btn.getBackground().mutate() as GradientDrawable
```

How to get the color from this Drawable?

Comment: Test case `ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748610/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod it is giving exception that `GradientDrawable` cannot be cast to `ColorDrawable`

Comment: You should use `ShapeDrawable` instead of `GradientDrawable `

Comment: @MuzammilHusnain can you please tell me more about how to use ShapeDrawable here

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
val color = (btn.background as? GradientDrawable)?.color?.defaultColor
```

**EDIT**

but [getColor(](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#getColor()))
only available on ***API 24 and above***. You should check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N` :

```
val color = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    (btn.background as? GradientDrawable)?.color?.defaultColor
} else null
```

Comment: It is throwing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : Method not found: MemberDescription(ownerInternalName = android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable, name = getColor, desc = ()Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;, isStatic = false)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val color = (btn.background as? ShapeDrawable)?.paint.color
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable: Ljava/lang/ClassCastException;` exception is coming

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the Drawable to Bitmap (link: [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)) and then get the Pixel at the center of it? Could not be the fastest way but one of the most compatible (because Gradient, Color or other type of Drawable are all flattened to a compatible Bitmap and you don't need to handle these differences)