# Android Compare Background Color with Color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-color

i am trying to make a little game.

There the Background color Randomly change from Blue to Green and back to Blue. If the user click the Blue "Button" then he lose.

My problem is how do i get the Background Color? and Compare it with R.color.colorGreen

I have tried some Examples from here but nothing works.

```java
if(Integer.parseInt(button.getBackground().toString()) == R.color.colorBlue)
```

Comment: In your random method that changes the background color, store the value, you can also make the comparison from there.

Comment: @DominiqueLorre No need. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089054/get-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-android/8089242).

> If you're on Android 3.0+ you can get the color *value*
>
> ```
> ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
> int color = buttonColor.getColor();
> ```

So, your revised `if` statement would be

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int color = buttonColor.getColor();
if (color == getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue)) {
    // if statement body
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Check my revised answer.

Comment: @Legendenkiller76 Does this work for you? If so please accept it